# how to sniff web form data from network when we login into the application using c#

Tags: c#

Basically i have a requirement to write a test case to sniff the credentials if we submitting and the form using HTTP.  below is my code and i am check the trace by enabling the system.net trace log.

from the trace am able to get the request and response data. but i need to sniff the credentials like how wireshark and the fiddler do.

```
public void samplePostWebReq()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://dummy.com/login");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
            request.Method = "POST";
            var loginData = new NameValueCollection
                {
                     { "username", "ghghg" },
                     { "password", "login@123" }
                };
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  

            var query = string.Join("&",
              loginData.Cast<string>().Select(key => $"{key}={loginData[key]}"));
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.  
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.  
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.  
            dataStream.Close();
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
          }
```

Configuration File App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
      <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>

    <trace autoflush="true" />

    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024"  tracemode="protocolonly">
        <listeners>
          <!--<add name="MyTraceFile"/>-->
          <add name="MyConsole"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>

      <source name="System.Net.Http">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyConsole"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
      <add
        name="MyTraceFile"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"
                />
      <add name="MyConsole" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
    </sharedListeners>

    <switches>
      <!--<add name="System.Net" value="Information" />-->
       <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>

  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

Comment: "i need to sniff the credentials like how wireshark and the fiddler do"  So essentially, you want to know how to listen for packets on the network, decode the data in the packets, then look for specific information in that data?  Seems like an entire program.  What part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: Listen for packets on the network